# CakePHP with PHPRTFLite

Tags: cakephp-1.3

How can I load the PHPRTFLite into a controller? I can load it into the view (using App::import('Vendor'....) and generate one file from the view currently. But under one action, I need to generate many files and save those on the server.

When I try to load it from the controller, it shows error messages like ...phprtf\FormHelper.php is not found. Why is it looking for FormHelper in the vendors/phprft folder?

If there is a way to load this into a model, please let me know as well.

Thank you very much for any help.

Best regards,
Tony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reply so far, strange. So after some playing around, here is how I got it to working:

The answer I have posted earlier worked, but was not clean.

Here is a way better method to use PHPRTFLite with CakePHP 1.3.

Step 1) Put the phprtf folder in the vendors folder in CakePHP

So **ls** in vendors will look like this will look like this:

phprtf
shells

**ls** in ..\vendors\phprtf will look like this: 
PHPRtfLite (Directory) 
PHPRtfLite.php

Step 2) Open this file: ..\config\bootstrap.php and enter the following inside:

```
 // The below lines will load the PHPRtfLite classes when required.

function loader($className){

    $classFile = '../vendors/phprtf/' . str_replace('_', '/', $className) . '.php';


    // check if file exists
     if(file_exists($classFile)) {
        require $classFile;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('loader');
```

So now you can use the PHPRtfLite classes in your Models to generate documents. I think they can be used from Controllers as well, but I haven't tried.

You can add more checks and so on to the code in the bootstrap.php if required.

I hope this helps someone. If you have comments, please let me know.

Cheers,
Tony.